# SQL запрос. Как посчитать кол-во записей по месяцам

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть таблица транзакций с данными за 3 месяца, в каждом месяце по одной а может быть и 2 записи:

запрос:

```
select a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, trunc(a.date,'MONTH'), count(*) a_count
      from a_transactions a
      where a.v_date between '01.03.2019' and '31.05.2019'
      group by a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, trunc(a.date,'MONTH');
```

результат:

```
      BRANCH         ACC       ID    TRUNC(A.DATE,'MONTH')    A_COUNT    
      ------ ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ---------- 
      1                3       154   01.03.2019                       1          
      1                3       154   01.04.2019                       1          
      1                3       154   01.05.2019                       1
```

За каждый месяц a_count вывела одну запись.
Мне нужно что бы a_count считала и количество за прежние месяцы то есть
если в марте a_count был равен 1, в апреле тоже есть запись, a_count уже должен быть равен 2 и если в мае тоже есть запись то a_count дожен быть 3

вот какой результат нужен:

```
      BRANCH         ACC       ID    TRUNC(A.DATE,'MONTH')      A_COUNT    
      ------ ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ---------- 
      1                3       154   01.03.2019                       1          
      1                3       154   01.04.2019                       2          
      1                3       154   01.05.2019                       3
```

Comment: `SUM(count(*)) OVER (ORDER BY trunc(a.date,'MONTH')) a_count`

Answer (score 1):

Этот расчет называется накопительный итог и довольно часто используется. В комментарии написали идею запроса для подсчета количества накопительным итогом - заворачиваем агрегатную функцию в оконную. Только, полагаю, вам надо подсчет вести в разрезе BRANCH, ACC, ID, тогда добавим ещё ограничение для окна:

```
select a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, trunc(a.date,'MONTH'), 
       sum(count(*)) OVER (partition by a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id order by trunc(a.date,'MONTH')) a_count
from a_transactions a
where a.v_date between '01.03.2019' and '31.05.2019'
group by a.branch, a.dt_acc, a.ct_id, trunc(a.date,'MONTH');
```